# Get child element of parent div jquery

Tags: jquery, parent-child, element

I have a div

```
<div id="customFormContact">
    .. other elements that don't matter ...
<input type="hidden" class="formID" value="Custom Product Contact" />    
</div>
```

I am using the div to do a jquery dialog with the submit button doing some ajax work.  In the ajax call I would like to do is pull out the value of the hidden field.  What is the best way to do so?

I have tried

```
var id = $("#customFormContact, .formID").val();
```

As well as

```
var id = $("#customFormContact > .formID").val();
```

to no avail.

With an alert of the value, I get either a undefinded (with the first) or a blank with the second.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Leave off the `,` ([multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)) and `>` ([child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)), just use a space like this:

```
var id = $("#customFormContact .formID").val();
```

With *only* a space is a [descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/), and it'll find a `.formID` as a child of any depth inside `#customFormContact`.

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Ug.  I think sometimes there is an element of, how hard we try to make things, when the easiest solution is more often the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

```
var id = $("#customFormContact .formID").val();
```

Comment: This is looking for a `<elem id="customFormContact"` class="formID">` element, both on the same, rather than a child.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
var id = $("#customFormContact .formID").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just give the field an ID

```
id = $('#someID').val();
```

Comment: I did not specify, there is the possibility of more than one element on the form bearing the class of formID. (ie. two different forms)